# Como retornar uma variável vinda de um formulário com anexo?

Tags: javascript, html5, node.js

'''
Quero que meu código retorne um valor/string a partir desse formulário:

```
<form action="/dashboard/busca_inserir" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
  <label for="empresas_file">Insira um documento, caso exista</label><br>
  <input type="file" name="empresas_file" /><br><br>
  <input type="submit" id="empresas_file" value="Submeter Arquivo" />
</div>
```

A função de retorno se encontra a baixo:

```
router.post('/busca_inserir', (req,res) => {

const empresas_file  = req.body.empresas_file;
console.log(empresas_file);
res.redirect('/dashboard/busca_inserir');});
```

Desse modo, o console log está sempre retornando "undefined" queria saber como consigo um valor para esse retorno.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo fato de estar passando um arquivo na requisição, por causa do enctype, é necessário algum pacote npm que faça a leitura (pelo menos é uma das alternativas), talvez o Multer ou connect-multiparty.

Por exemplo:

```
npm install --save connect-multiparty
```

agora, como middleware (O app é o objeto do express)

```
const multiparty = require("connect-multiparty");
app.use(multiparty());
```

Mais um detalhe: use 'req.files'

```
router.post('/busca_inserir', (req,res) => {

const empresas_file  = req.files.empresas_file;
console.log(empresas_file);
res.redirect('/dashboard/busca_inserir');});
```